# Does anybody know what company made this spatula?

Tags: equipment, utensils

I received the following spatula and I want to buy another one, but I can't find it. Does anyone recognize the company?

[image]

Comment: Inox 18/0 is a grade of steel, not a brand. Could you post a picture of the actual spatula?

Comment: @GdD I guess the owl(?) could be an indicator.

Comment: I tried with the owl, but doesn't appear on google.

Comment: Yes, I know that inox 18/0 is a grade of steel. I didn't know what is the owl.

Comment: "Inox" is typical of European manufacturers; standing for " not oxidizable" meaning stainless steel .

Comment: I've had a little try at reverse image searching with suitable companion terms, and not got anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is right there. It is an INOX spatula.
This one has the same ridges on the handle.

http://www.100x100chef.com/index.php/eng/shop/collection-retail/inox-retail2/retail-plating-spatula-detail.html

Comment: INOX isn't a brand.

Comment: INOX is a pseudo-brand used on all kind of stainless steel items. 18/0 means 18% chromium, 0% nickel. The brand on the item on that website is actually "100% Chef". The one you have might too be from "100% chef", or something by the same OEM maker sold to a different label.

Comment: @Catija : yes it is : http://www.inoxkitchenware.com/ .  There are a few others, though, too.  But this does look like the spatula in the picture

Comment: @Joe that's not a brand. That's a generic site that specializes in products made from inox... I found no items on that site that have that logo. The items that *do* have logos say "Cuisinox".

Comment: The 18/0 is odd . There is an 18 Cr ferritic stainless ( SAE 430) but this would be a strange application. A magnet could decide ; if magnetic it likely is 18 Cr . If non-magnetic , it is likely 18-8 or 18-10.

Comment: Based on the link provided in the answer, the brand is 100% Chef. In this link, it does appear to be the same spatula: http://www.100x100chef.info/index.php/eng/novelties/accessorios-plating-retail-detail.html .